# Recyclerview multiple selection selected order count similar to instagram image selection

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, multipleselection

### Problem

I am trying to develop a gallery selector page for my app. A user can select multiple images/videos from the listed items (from the users phone). The user can select up to 10 items at once and the order of selection should be shown for each item. The selection order should also adjust based on selection and deselection.

eg : If user deselects selection 1 then all other selection after selection 1 should decrement by one.

### What I have done

I have already made the recyclerview adapter with diffUtils and handled the multiple selection using `recyclerview-selection` library. But I can't find a way to show the selection order and adjusting it based on user action.

### What an trying to achieve

[image: instagram selection ui]

### Code

**GalleryAdapter**

```
public class GalleryViewAdapter extends ListAdapter<GalleryThumbnailsModel,GalleryViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<GalleryThumbnailsModel> selectedItemModels;

    private Interaction interaction;
    private SelectionTracker<Long> selectionTracker;

    private static int POST_TYPE_IMAGE = 1;
    private static int POST_TYPE_VIDEO = 3;

    public GalleryViewAdapter(GalleryViewDiffCallback diffCallback,Context context,ArrayList<GalleryThumbnailsModel> selectedItemModels) {
        super(diffCallback);
        this.context = context;
        this.selectedItemModels = selectedItemModels;

        setHasStableIds(true);
    }
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public GalleryViewAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_gallery_view,parent,false);
        return new GalleryViewAdapter.ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final GalleryViewAdapter.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        GalleryThumbnailsModel item = getItem(position);
        holder.bind(item,selectionTracker.isSelected((long) position));
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return (long) position;
    }

    public void setSelectionTracker(SelectionTracker<Long> selectionTracker) {
        this.selectionTracker = selectionTracker;
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        ImageView postImage;
        ImageView postTypeVideo;
        ProgressBar progressBar;
        TextView postOrderCount;

        FrameLayout selectedIcon;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            postImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_gallery_image);
            postTypeVideo = itemView.findViewById(R.id.user_post_video);
            progressBar = itemView.findViewById(R.id.progress_loader);
            selectedIcon =itemView.findViewById(R.id.gallery_selected_item);
            postOrderCount = itemView.findViewById(R.id.selected_post_order);
        }

        public void bind(GalleryThumbnailsModel item, boolean selected) {

            new GlideImageLoader(context,postImage,progressBar).load(item.getThumbnail(),null);

            if(selected){
                selectedIcon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                interaction.onItemSelected(getAdapterPosition(),item);
            }else {
                selectedIcon.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                interaction.onItemDeselected(getAdapterPosition(),item);
            }

            if(item.getMediaType() == POST_TYPE_VIDEO){
                postTypeVideo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }else {
                postTypeVideo.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        }

        public ItemDetailsLookup.ItemDetails<Long> getItemDetails(){
            return new ItemDetailsLookup.ItemDetails<Long>() {
                @Override
                public int getPosition() {
                    return getAdapterPosition();
                }

                @Nullable
                @Override
                public Long getSelectionKey() {
                    return getItemId();
                }

                @Override
                public boolean inSelectionHotspot(@NonNull MotionEvent e) {
                    return true;
                }
            };
        }
    }

    public static class GalleryViewDiffCallback extends DiffUtil.ItemCallback<GalleryThumbnailsModel>{

        @Override
        public boolean areItemsTheSame(@NonNull GalleryThumbnailsModel oldItem, @NonNull GalleryThumbnailsModel newItem) {
            return oldItem.getUriPath().equals(newItem.getUriPath());
        }

        @Override
        public boolean areContentsTheSame(@NonNull GalleryThumbnailsModel oldItem, @NonNull GalleryThumbnailsModel newItem) {
            return oldItem.equals(newItem);
        }
    }

    public interface Interaction{
        void onItemSelected(int position,GalleryThumbnailsModel item);
        void onItemDeselected(int position,GalleryThumbnailsModel item);
    }

    public void setInteraction(Interaction interaction) {
        this.interaction = interaction;
    }
}
```

**Setting adapter in Fragment**

```
  private void setAdapter() {

        galleryViewAdapter = new GalleryViewAdapter(new GalleryViewAdapter.GalleryViewDiffCallback(),context,selectedItemsModels);
        gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(context,3,RecyclerView.VERTICAL,false);
        galleryViewAdapter.submitList(galleryThumbnailsModels);
        galleryViewRecycler.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
        galleryViewRecycler.setHasFixedSize(true);
        galleryViewRecycler.setAdapter(galleryViewAdapter);

        selectionTracker = new SelectionTracker.Builder<Long>(
                "selection",
                galleryViewRecycler,
                new StableIdKeyProvider(galleryViewRecycler),
                new RecyclerSelectionLookup(galleryViewRecycler),
                StorageStrategy.createLongStorage()
        ).withSelectionPredicate(new SelectionTracker.SelectionPredicate<Long>() {
            @Override
            public boolean canSetStateForKey(@NonNull Long key, boolean nextState) {
                // 10 - max selection size
                return !nextState || selectionTracker.getSelection().size() < 10;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean canSetStateAtPosition(int position, boolean nextState) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean canSelectMultiple() {
                return true;
            }
        })
                .build();

        selectionTracker.addObserver(new SelectionTracker.SelectionObserver<Long>() {
            @Override
            public void onSelectionChanged() {
                super.onSelectionChanged();
                int selectedItemCount = selectionTracker.getSelection().size();
                if(selectedItemCount == 0){
                    addMediaLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }else if(selectedItemCount > 0 && selectedItemCount < 11){
                    selectedCountTextView.setText(String.valueOf(selectedItemCount));
                    addMediaLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }
        });

        galleryViewAdapter.setSelectionTracker(selectionTracker);


        galleryViewAdapter.setInteraction(new GalleryViewAdapter.Interaction() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(int position,GalleryThumbnailsModel item) {
                item.setSelectedOrder(selectedItemsModels.size()+1);
                selectedItemsModels.add(item);
            }

            @Override
            public void onItemDeselected(int position,GalleryThumbnailsModel item) {

            }
        });
    }
```

I am only adding the adapter code here. Otherwise the question would become too large.I will share the complete code if this doesn't provide necessary information.

Answer (score 1):

you can pass selectionTracker.selection.size() to bind function in your ViewHolder class, so you will have always the latest count

```
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final GalleryViewAdapter.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

       int count = selectionTracker.selection.size()
        holder.bind(item,count,selectionTracker.isSelected((long) position));
    }
```

Comment: this works, but if adapter call notifyDataSetChanged(), then all items showing the same things ( i.e selection.size() ).